# Stereo camera reprojected points form cone shape

Tags: c++, opencv

I am following the steps at Martin Peris's blog

http://blog.martinperis.com/2012/01/3d-reconstruction-with-opencv-and-point.html

and have calibrated a stereo camera setup and created a depth map. My Q matrix looks like this:

> 1. 1. 1. -1.6653794479370117e+002 0. 1. 0. -1.9214219284057617e+002
> 2. 1. 1. 9.5886163747058333e+002 0. 0. 4.1031825219069389e-002
>            3.3725873827607686e+000

my depth, this:

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/34ovofr/8]

When i triangulate, either with the depth map method, or by :

> d = pointRightImage.X - pointLeftImage.X;
>
> X = pointLeftImage.X * Q[0, 0] + Q[0, 3]; Y = pointLeftImage.Y * Q[1,
>   1] + Q[1, 3]; Z = Q[2, 3]; W = d * Q[3, 2] + Q[3, 3];
>
> X = X / W; Y = Y / W; Z = Z / W;

My points come out as this:

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/119rmmq/8]

Two strange cone shapes. I have read enough to know that other people have had this problem, but i can't find a solution. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: The link to the Martin Peris blog post is broken; can you update it?

Comment: yes, yes i can... done!

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, so I'm not posting this as an answer. Try swapping the camera image and the depth image? According to the tutorial, I would have expected the camera image to be turned into points (with colors and everything) but the depth signal seems to be what's displayed.